# Redirecting the result files to different variable file names

Tags: bash

I have a folder with, say, ten data files `I01.txt`, ..., `I10.txt`.. Each file, when executed using the command `/a.out`, gives me five output files, namely `f1.txt`, `f2.txt`, ... `f5.txt`.

I have written a simple bash program to execute all the files and save the output printed on the screen to a variable file using the command

```
./ cosima_peaks_444_temp_muuttuva  -args > $counter-res.txt.
```

Using this, I am able to save the on screen output to the file. But the five files `f1` to `f5` are altered to store results of the last file run, in this case `I10`, and the results of the first nine files are lost.

So I  want to save the output of each `I*.txt` file (`f1` ... `f5`) to a a different file such that, when the program executes `I01.txt`, using `./a.out` it stores the output of the files

```
f1>var1-f1.txt ,    f2>var1-f2.txt... f5 > var1-f5.txt
```

and then repeats the same for `I02`  (`f1>var2-f1.txt` ...).

```
#!/bin/bash

# echo "for looping over all the .txt files"
echo -e "Enter the name of the file or q to quit "
read dir
if [[ $dir = q ]]
then        
    exit
fi

filename="$dir*.txt"
counter=0

if [[ $dir == I ]]
then
    for f in $filename ; do
        echo "output of $filename"
        ((counter ++))
        ./cosima_peaks_444_temp_muuttuva $f -m202.75 -c1 -ng0.5 -a0.0 -b1.0 -e1.0 -lg > $counter-res.txt 
        echo "counter $counter"
    done
fi
```

Comment: You need to change `a.out`, which I assume is written in C.  It should not be a difficult job to alter the C, but otherwise there is no way bash can tell which file the C program is processing at any one time.

Comment: Is `a.out` simply reading the contents of the directory (e.g. with `opendir` or `scandir`), or are you *passing* `l01.txt`, `l02.txt`, etc.. as arguments to the program?

Comment: Here ./cosima_peaks_444_muuttuva is a.out.   and the executable file is written in fortran 90.

Comment: David C. Rankin the a.out is the executable for a program i had compiled before. I am passing I01.txt .. and a few other arguments to the program

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you want to pass files `l01.txt`, `l02.txt`, ... to `a.out` and save the output for each execution of `a.out` to a separate file like `f01.txt`, `f02.txt`, ..., then you could use a short script that reads each file named `l*.txt` in the directory and passes the value to `a.out` redirecting the output to a file `fN.txt` (were `N` is the same number in the `lN.txt` filename.) This presumes you are passing each filename to `a.out` and that `a.out` is not reading the entire directory automatically.

```
for i in l*.txt; do 
    num=$(sed 's/^l\(.*\)[.]txt/\1/' <<<"$i")
    ./a.out "$i" > "f${num}.txt"
done
```

(**note:** that is `'s/(lowercase L) ... /\one..'`)

*note:* if you do not want the same `N` from the filename (with its leading `'0'`), then you can trim the leading `'0'` from the `N` value for the output filename.

(you can use a `counter` as you have shown in your edited post, but you have no guarantee in sort order of the filenames used by the loop unless you explicitly sort them)

*note:*, this presumes NO `spaces` or embedded `newline` or other odd characters in the filename. If your `lN.txt` names can have odd characters or spaces, then feeding a `while` loop with `find` can avoid the odd character issues.

---

**With `f1` - `f5` Created Each Run**

You know the format for the output file name, so you can test for the existence of an existing file name and set a *prefix* or *suffix* to provide unique names. For example, if your first pass creates filenames `'pass1-f01.txt'`, `'pass1-f02.txt'`, then you can check for that pattern (in several ways) and increment your `'passN'` prefix as required:

```
for f in "$filename"; do 
    num=$(sed 's/l*\(.*\)[.]txt/\1/' <<<"$f")
    count=$(sed 's/^0*//' <<<"$num")
    while [ -f "pass${count}-f${num}.txt" ]; do
        ((count++))
    done
    ./a.out "$f" > "pass${count}-f${num}.txt"
done
```

Give that a try and let me know if that isn't closer to what you need.

(*note:* the use of the *herestring* (`<<<`) is bash-only, if you need a portable solution, pipe the output of `echo "$var"` to `sed`, e.g. `count=$(echo "$num" | sed 's/^0*//')` )

Comment: I am sorry for being ambiguous. when I pass I01.txt to a.out it gives me five files namely f1..f5.txt. the results in  f1..f5 files are then replaced when i pass I02.txt through a.out. So I basically want to run I01 and save the five output files f1..f5 into five separate files like var1....var1-f5 so that thy would not be altered when I happen to run I02...I10 files

Comment: OK, now I see what you are wanting to do, let me think a bit and I'll edit the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have the source code of this a.out binary. If so, I would modify it so that it outputs to several fds instead of several files. Then you can solve this very cleanly using redirects:

```
./a.out 3> fileX.1 4> fileX.2 5> fileX.3
```

and so on for every file you want to output. Writing to a file or to a (redirected) fd is equivalent in most programs (notable exception: memory mapped I/O, but that is not commonly used for such scripts - look for `mmap` calls)

Note that this is not very esoteric, but a very well known technique that is regularly used to separate output (stdout, fd=1) from errors (stderr, fd=2).

Answer (score 0):

I replaced your `cosima_peaks_444_temp_muuttuva`  with a `function myprog`.
The OP asked for more explanation, so I put in a lot of comment:

```
# This function makes 5 output files for testing the construction
function myprog {
   # Fill the test output file f1.txt with the input filename and a datestamp
   echo "Output run $1 on $(date)" > f1.txt
   # The original prog makes 5 output files, so I copy the new testfile 4 times
   cp f1.txt f2.txt
   cp f1.txt f3.txt
   cp f1.txt f4.txt
   cp f1.txt f5.txt
}

# Use the number in the inputfile for making a unique filename and move the output
function move_output {
   # The parameter ${1} is filled with something like I03.txt
   # You can get the number with a sed action, but it is more efficient to use
   # bash functions, even in 2 steps. 
   # First step: Cut off from the end as much as possiple (%%) starting with a dot.
   Inumber=${1%%.*}
   # Step 2: Remove the I from the Inumber (that is filled with something like "I03").
   number=${Inumber#I}
   # Move all outputfiles from last run
   for outputfile in f*txt; do
      # Put the number in front of the original name
      mv "${outputfile}" "${number}_${outputfile}"
   done
}

# Start the main processing. You will perform the same logic for all input files,
# so make a loop for all files. I guess all input files start with an "I",
# followed by 2 characters (a number), and .txt. No need to use ls for listing those.

for input in I??.txt; do
   # Call the dummy prog above with the name of the first input file as a parameter
   myprog "${input}"
   # Now finally the show starts.
   # Call the function for moving the 5 outputfiles to another name.
   move_output "${input}"
done
```

Comment: Hi can you please explain the above segment. Thank you.

Comment: @Carlton: See answer.